# How to set up an ASP.NET MVC 3 sub-application in IIS 7?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, web-applications, iis-7

I try set up an MVC 3 sup-application on IIS 7. Root app is a MVC 3 application too.

So, my root app runs on www.mysite.com - sub-app must be www.myapp.com/subapp

I think the problem is in web.config...

Comment: what problem are you having? Are you getting an error?

Comment: have you mapped the sub application? with wich params?

Comment: Can you get the details of error? Look a the body of your response and paste it here please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application and sub application have to be running on the same version of .NET.

In addition, there is a parent/child relationship with the web.configs - so the child application will inherit the parents web.config unless told not to do so using 'inheritInChildApplications' in the configs.