# Relative URLs broken when ASP.net MVC application added to existing web site in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

It seems that the relative paths from our @Url.Actions break when the application is "added" to an existing web site in IIS.

Steps:

1. Develop application with @Url.Action links.
2. Deploy application to IIS.
3. Go to an existing web site in IIS Manager, right click and "Add Application".
4. Relative links are now broken

Our action code looks like this:
     @Url.Action("Search", "Home")

Our added application with it's alias looks like this:

http://myexistingapplication/my-new-added-application-alias

Thanks in advance for any help offered.

Comment: So what the result Url generated by `@Url.Action("Search", "Home")` ?

Comment: You have an application within an application? Do you have custom routing in your existing application?

Comment: Igor, the Url.Action if used in a form action or to build a hyperlink will always result in a 404 page not found. Also, none of the dependent css style sheets or javascript files will be found.

Comment: Ross, only at the IIS level is the application within an application. This is achieved through the IIS Manager.... An example usage scenario would be if you had an application that existed for years, and you have written some new application and would like for it to hang of off the existing applications hostname/web site. No custom routing.

Comment: @ChristopherCrisis Url.Action renders a *string* with url. Which you can render inside your `*.aspx` page. So what's result url? I understand that if you navigate this url, you'll get 404.

Comment: the result is: http://myexistingwebsite/my-new-added-application-alias/Home/Search

Comment: Please check if this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15917222/1220550 or this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9296707/1220550

Comment: Hi Peter B, thank you but neither of these resolved the issue.

Comment: I have found the issue, but not a solution... There is a rewrite rule in my Parent app which seems to be breaking the linking. I need to figure out how to not apply it to my child app:     <match url="*"/>
     <conditions>
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
     </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the following rule so to override the Wordpress rewrites which were breaking my MVC routing.

```
       <rule name="my-application-alias" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="my-application-alias" />
      </rule>
```

Found the answer here:

http://bluetoque.ca/2010/12/installing-an-mvc-application-in-a-subdirectory-of-wordpress/